# extracting digits from a number using stringTokenizer

Tags: java, string, java-io

given a number (user input) 01111000

I want to extract the individual digits 0,1,1,1.....

Is it possible using stringtokenizer, I have tried empty strings, "//d" , "?" but it doesn't work...

specific to stringtokenizer only

Comment: downvoter, please provide reason for downvote

Comment: please please answer if it is possible using stringtokenizer only

Comment: Why do you want to use StringTokenizer for something that is better done in other ways? Also, from the Javadoc - "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."

Comment: can you post what have you tried so far?

Comment: because I am creating an API that must spit out tokens

Comment: But StringTokenizer just retruns Strings. There's absolutely no need to use StringTokenizer instead of other options like String.split that would also return Strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "01111000";
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(s.split("(?<=\\G.)")));
```

Which produces

```
[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why `Tokenizer`? Use a `loop` and a [`charAt(position)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)).

If you still want `Tokenizer`, use this *trick*:

```
String number = "01111000010".replaceAll("", " ");
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(number," ");
```

Comment: because i am creating an api that spits out tokens